# Can I shorten Windows Explorer thumbnail display of file paths?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I have Windows Explorer set to Show Full Path In Title bar. For me, it is essential to see that information in the title bar. However this causes an issue for the "thumbnail" views.

When I have a number of Windows Explorer windows open to different folders, I can use the task bar Explorer icon to show "thumbnails" of all the folders. Or I can use Alt-Tab to see thumbnails of all windows.

In both cases the Explorer paths are all truncated to only show the first part, and they all look the same. I see a dozen thumbnails that look like "C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\Nam..."

All the differences are below the \Documents level.

I tried using SUBST E: "C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents" and then using E: for Documents.

This has several problems:

1. Deleting files from E: disables use of Recycle Bin
2. The SUBST drive letter cannot be included in Quick Access
3. The SUBST drive cannot be named (I would like to name it "Documents") It must be the same drive name as the physical drive it is on (e.g. C:)

Is there another approach to shorten the displayed path to the Documents folder?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to shortening names to create a directory link, so the folder
`C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents` will have the alternate name of `C:\short`.
I have not tested how it works in the problem cases, but it should perform
better since it is still inside the same disk.
I think you cannot create a directory link in the root folder `C:\`, so you
might need to create a short sub-folder name, even one letter, such as `C:\d`
and create the link inside it.

The Windows command to use is
[mklink](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink),
which has two variants:

Soft link pointing to a directory:

```
mklink /D Link Target
```

Hard link pointing to a directory, also known as a directory junction:

```
mklink /J Link Target
```

For more information about links, see for example the article
[The Complete Guide to Creating Symbolic Links (aka Symlinks) on Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/).